# How would I write cycle as a lambda function?

Tags: haskell

Just for fun, here is my own version of `cycle`:

```
myCycle :: [a] -> [a]
myCycle xs = xs ++ myCycle xs
```

The right-hand side refers to both the function name `myCycle` and the parameter `xs`.

Is it possible to implement `myCycle` *without* mentioning `myCycle` or `xs` on the right-hand side?

```
myCycle = magicLambdaFunction
```

Comment: `myCycle = \xs -> let ys = xs ++ ys in ys`. `fix` inlined.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it possible to implement `myCycle` without mentioning `myCycle` or `xs` on the right-hand side?

The answer is yes and no (not necessarily in that order).

Other people have mentioned the fixed point combinator.  If you have a fixed-point combinator `fix :: (a -> a) -> a`, then as you mention in a comment to Pubby's answer, you can write `myCycle = fix . (++)`.

But the standard definition of `fix` is this:

```
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = let r = f r in r

-- or alternatively, but less efficient:
fix' f = f (fix' f)
```

Note that the definition of `fix` involves mentioning a left-hand-side variable on the right hand side of its definition (`r` in the first definition, `fix'` in the second one).  So what we've really done so far is push the problem down to just `fix`.

The interesting thing to note is that Haskell is based on a typed lambda calculus, and for good technical reason most typed lambda calculi are designed so that they *cannot* "natively" express the fixed point combinator.  These languages only become Turing-complete if you add some extra feature "on top" of the base calculus that allows for computing fixed points.  For example, any of these will do:

1. Add `fix` as a primitive to the calculus.
2. Add recursive data types (which Haskell has; this is another way of defining `fix` in Haskell).
3. Allow the definitions to refer to the left-hand side identifier being defined (which Haskell also has).

This is a useful type of modularity for many reasons—one being that a lambda calculus without fixed points is also a consistent proof system for logic, another that `fix`-less programs in many such systems can be proven to terminate.

---

**EDIT:** Here's `fix` written with recursive types.  Now the definition of `fix` itself is not recursive, but the definition of the `Rec` type is:

```
-- | The 'Rec' type is an isomorphism between @Rec a@ and @Rec a -> a@:
--
-- > In  :: (Rec a -> a) -> Rec a
-- > out :: Rec a        -> (Rec a -> a)
--
-- In simpler words:
--
-- 1. Haskell's type system doesn't allow a function to be applied to itself.
--
-- 2. @Rec a@ is the type of things that can be turned into a function that
--    takes @Rec a@ arguments.
--
-- 3. If you have @foo :: Rec a@, you can apply @foo@ to itself by doing
--    @out foo foo :: a@.  And if you have @bar :: Rec a -> a@, you can do 
--    @bar (In bar)@.
--
newtype Rec a = In { out :: Rec a -> a }

-- | This version of 'fix' is just the Y combinator, but using the 'Rec'
-- type to get around Haskell's prohibition on self-application (see the
-- expression @out x x@, which is @x@ applied to itself):
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = (\x -> f (out x x)) (In (\x -> f (out x x)))
```

Answer (score 6):

I think this works:

```
myCycle = \xs -> fix (xs ++)
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator

> In programming languages that support anonymous functions, fixed-point combinators allow the definition and use of anonymous recursive functions, i.e. without having to bind such functions to identifiers. In this setting, the use of fixed-point combinators is sometimes called anonymous recursion.

Comment: And according to lambdabot, this can be simplified to `fix . (++)` :)

Comment: @FredOverflow I don't know if I would call that simplified!

Comment: According to lambdabot's definition of simplified :)

Comment: Haskell's `fix` encapsulates the very concept of "mentioning the name on the RHS" since it's defined as `fix f = f (fix f)` so it's perhaps a little bit unfair. The best answer is probably the [Y combinator](http://r6.ca/blog/20060919T084800Z.html). Take note, though, that to get a well-typed Y combinator that post needs to use recursive data type which use the name of the datatype on the RHS. I don't know if it's possible to get a Y combinator to type without using a recursive type.

Comment: @tel: It's not possible without using a recursive *something*, but there are other ways. As usual, [Oleg has a few interesting ideas](http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/fixed-point-combinators.html).

Answer (score 5):

For fun this is another stuff :

```
let f = foldr (++) [] . repeat
```

or

```
let f = foldr1 (++) . repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

No one pointed out the "obvious" version of the fix solution yet. The idea is that you transform the named recursive call into a parameter.

```
let realMyCycle = fix (\myCycle xs -> xs ++ myCycle xs)
```

This "recursive name" introducing trick is pretty much what `let in` does in Haskell. The only difference is that using the built-in construct is more straightforward and probably nicer for the implementation.